# Redux + React + FireBase: how to use a state when updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

## Hello guys and girls :)

I'm starting with Firebase && Redux and I'm having some issues with the callback `on`-function of `firebase.database().ref()` within the formular

```
function getAll() {

    const uid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        .uid;


    const dbRef = firebase.database()
        .ref().child('events');

    const userRef = dbRef.child(uid);

    let answer = [];

    userRef.on('value', snap => {
        let rx = snap.val();
        for (let item in snap.val()) {
            answer.push(rx[ item ]);
        }
    });

    return Promise.resolve({
        events: answer
    });
}
```

### What was I doing ?

I've created before some actions (triggers) to call this services and this method must fire before the result be saved with reducers in the `store`.

This is what is expected. *But*,...

### What is my actual reality ?

- The method fires in time, good new :-) *but*,
- The `callback` (as it is) fires some seconds after (`1` or `1.5s`) while the `redux` itself, very fast unit, fires and make the react render at the same time. In short, the components are rendered lots before the firebase callback gives back a value.

At the final then I need to render, reload the page, change to another route of the application so that the saved changes can be applied to render.

Since I'm beginning with *redux* and *firebase*, I'm not `100%` (but only `70%`) sure of this deductions, but they are the betters I could've found in this situation.

### What's then the situation ?

I'm starving for any help now and thank you for any help you could provide me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey buddy I started with Firebase this January did a whole project and I know the struggle for finding information.

The answer to your question is you need to use sagas.

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Sagas are a way to sync your API calls so they are called before your reducer dispatches an action and makes it possible to control synchronous API calls.

For example,

```
function* addAnswer{
    const user = yield call(Api.addAnswer, action.payload.userId); 
    yield put({type: "REQUEST_USER_ANSWER_SUCCEEDED", user: user});
}
```

Sagas will wait for the call to end in yield before it continues. Then you bind this function to an action.

```
function* mySaga() {
    yield takeEvery("REQUEST_USER_ANSWER", fetchUser);
}
```

And you add to your store the redux-saga middleware

`const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
// mount it on the Store
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)`

Basically, what happens here is each time you answer you want to be binded to the saga action REQUEST_USER_ANSWER which then if succeeds triggers the REQUEST_USER_ANSWER_SUCCEEDED which you want your reducer to be binded too. This way you know the reducer triggers only if the API call is done and succeed.

People either use Saga or Thunk in their projects which provide the same work but you absolutly need one of those.

Comment: Very well ! I'll study the method. Thank you very much for your very fast answer. Though I was having `redux-thunk` installed, I didn't knew why. Thanks again !

Comment: You're welcome and please accept the answer if you are satisfied!